# For loop not working right

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop

I would like to run a for loop that will insert a word in a text box from a table; then insert a new word in a text box right after that.

However i only get one word when i click submit is there a way to do this without ajax?

```
function check()
{
  var myrows = new Array();
  myrows[0] = "row1";
  myrows[1] = "row2";

  var server =" ";
  var root = " ";

  for (var i=0;i<myrows.length;i++){

    root = myrows[i]+ "rootname";
    server = myrows[i]+ "servername";
    var j = document.getElementById(root);
    var y = document.getElementById(server);

    document.getElementById('id_rootname').value=j.textContent;
    document.getElementById('id_servername').value=y.textContent;

  }

  var x;
  var r=confirm("Are you sure you?" );
  if (r==true)
  {
    x="You pressed OK!";
  }
  else
  {
    Object.cancel;
  }  

}
</script>


        <tr >
    <td align="center"><input type="checkbox"  class="selectedId"
    onclick="resetSelectedAll(this);" id= "check" value="row1" name="row{{ forloop.counter }" ></td> 
                <td name = "root" id="row1rootname">appBOWSERtest033</td>
                <td style="display:none;" name = "server" id="row1servername">Bowser</td>
                <td name= "url" id="row1urls">21</td>
                <td id="row1custs">3</td>
                <td id="row1jvmms"> 1024</td>
                <td id="row1x64">1</td>
                <td id="row1currentplatform"> platform_11.3.111129.38873</td>
                <td id="row1currentjdk"> jdk_1.6.0_26-b03</td>
                <td id="row1currenttomcat">tomcat_6.0.32</td>
            </tr>



            <tr >
    <td align="center"><input type="checkbox"  class="selectedId"
    onclick="resetSelectedAll(this);" id= "check" value="row2" name="row{{ forloop.counter }" ></td> 
                <td name = "root" id="row2rootname">appLUIGItest033</td>
                <td style="display:none;" name = "server" id="row2servername">LUIGI</td>
                <td name= "url" id="row2urls">12</td>
                <td id="row2custs">3</td>
                <td id="row2jvmms"> 1024</td>
                <td id="row2x64">0</td>
                <td id="row2currentplatform"> platform_12.1.120510.42747</td>
                <td id="row2currentjdk"> jdk_1.6.0_31-b04</td>
                <td id="row2currenttomcat">tomcat_7.0.27</td>
            </tr>
    <form action=" " id ="forms" name = "forms" >{% csrf_token %}
 <table>
<tr><th><label for="id_servername">Servername:</label></th><td><input id="id_servername" maxlength="50" name="servername" type="text" value="LUIGI" /></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_rootname">Rootname:</label></th><td><input id="id_rootname" maxlength="50" name="rootname" type="text" value="appLUIGItest033" /></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_action">Action:</label></th><td><select id="id_action" name="action">
<option value="Restart" selected="selected">Restart</option>
<option value="Full_Dump">Full_Dump</option>
<option value="Redeploy">Redeploy</option>
<option value="Thread">Thread</option>
</select></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_loginname">Loginname:</label></th><td><ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul><input id="id_loginname" maxlength="50" name="loginname" type="text" /></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_choice">Choice:</label></th><td><ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul><input id="id_choice" name="choice" type="checkbox" /></td></tr>
</table>
<input name = "hello" type="submit" onclick="check()" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I don't get it, the form is submitted and the page reloads, so your javascript is lost, right ?

Comment: yes i would like it to run it get the content then run it again does javascript contain a serialization function or something to store the data, because i intend to run 2 post after i get this to work

Comment: where is the id_rootname,id_servername in your html code.can you modify it.

Comment: that is what log.as_table is produced as ill display that code

Comment: @justinprice try my answer i got the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
root = myrows[i]+ "rootname";
server = myrows[i]+ "servername";
var j = document.getElementById(root);
var y = document.getElementById(server);

 instead of this try this one.



start var i = 1 in for loop.
var j= document.getElementById("row"+i+"rootname");
```

Comment: Thank you, but that is giving me the same issue as my original input i have actually tried this before initially I am assuming on submit the page refreshes the for loop stops thank you for trying

Comment: @justinprice submit is not the problem.

Comment: i assume my error is coming from the django not the html or  javascript